# For $\Sigma = \{ 0,1 \}$, $A$ has strings which contain a $1$ in their middle third, and a $B$ which contain two $1$'s in their middle third.

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Language $A$ can also be represented as, $$A = \{ uvw \mid u,w \in \Sigma^*\text{ and, }v \in \Sigma^* 1 \Sigma^*\text{ and, }|u| = |w| \ge |v| \}$$

Language $B$ can also be represented as, $$B = \{ uvw \mid u,w \in \Sigma^*\text{ and, }v \in \Sigma^* 1 \Sigma^* 1 \Sigma^*\text{ and, }|u| = |w| \ge |v| \}$$

I have to prove that $A$ is CFL & $B$ is not a CFL.

To prove $A$ is CFL, I have to show that a  CFG can be made.
I made a CFG for this equation:

$$L = \{ uv \mid u \in \Sigma^*\text{ and, }v \in \Sigma^* 1 \Sigma^*\text{ and, }|u| \ge |v| \}$$
which is,
$$ S \to XSX \mid T1 $$
$$ T \to XT \mid X $$
$$ X \to 0 \mid 1 $$

But I am not able to make a perfect CFG for $A$ after much trying although they seem both same ..

Can I prove $B$ is not a CFL maybe by using pumping lemma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**18 April 2022: The answer given for $A$ was absurd, and I’ve deleted it.**

**9 May 2022: I’ve now added a correct answer in the blockquote below.**

> Consider the context-free grammar with initial symbol $S$ and the following productions:
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> S&\to XLX\mid XRX\\
> L&\to XLXX\mid C\mid 1\\
> R&\to XXRX\mid C\mid 1\\
> C&\to XCX\mid 1\\
> X&\to 0\mid 1
> \end{align*}$$
>
> - Show that the derivations that begin with the production $S\to XLX$ generate $$\{u1v\in\Sigma^*:|u|\le|v|<2|u|\}\,,\tag{1}$$ and those that begin with the production $S\to XRX$ generate $$\{u1v\in\Sigma^*:|v|\le|v|<2|v|\}\,.\tag{2}$$
> - Show that $(1)$ is the set of strings $w=u1v\in\Sigma^*$ such that the indicated $1$ is in the middle third of $w$, and $|u|\le|v|$, and $(2)$ is the set of strings $w=u1v\in\Sigma^*$ such that the indicated $1$ is in the middle third of $w$, and $|v|\le|u|$. Clearly $A$ is the union of these two sets.

To show that $B$ is not context-free, use the pumping lemma with the word $s=0^{p+2}10^p10^{p+2}$, where $p$ is the pumping length. You’ll have $s=uvwxy$, where $|vwx|\le p$, $|vx|\ge 1$, and $uv^kwx^ky\in B$ for all $k\ge 0$, and you’ll have to consider several cases according to the possible decompositions of $s$. Note that since $|vwx|\le p$, at most two of the strings of $0$s can be pumped.

Comment: if we take $ u,v\in\Sigma^* $ then how can we have $ |u|,|v|\ge 1 $ ??

Comment: @Harshal: I don’t see the problem: the only word in $\Sigma^*$ that I’m excluding with the condition that the length is at least $1$ is the empty word.

Comment: Alright!!:) .. so here will the grammer will be $S \to 0S1 | 1 | 1S0 $ & $ T \to XTX | X $ & $ X \to 1 | 0 $ ? .. I am not sure ..maybe this will satisfy the all the strings for A ?

Comment: @Harshal: Your grammar generates the word $1$, which isn’t in $A$. Try $S\to X1X$, and then have $X$ generate any non-empty string.

Comment: so, $ X \to 1 | 0 | 1X | X1 | 0X | X0 $ ? to accept strings of all kind ?

Comment: @Harshal: That will work fine, but you can cut it down to $X\to 0\mid 1\mid 0X\mid 1X$ without losing anything.

Comment: but how will we ensure from the previous definition of $A$, where $|u| = |w|$ ?

Comment: @Harshal: You should be able to show that if you take any word of the form $u1v$, where $u$ and $v$ are non-empty, you can write it in the form $xyz$, where $|x|=|z|\ge|y|$, and $y\in\Sigma^*1\Sigma^*$. HINT: If $|u|\le|v|$, take $z=v$, and if $|u|<|v|$, take $x=u$.

Comment: Alright !! :) .. Thank you again professor :)

Comment: @Harshal: You’re welcome!

Comment: I'm not convinced these two languages are equivalent. Doesn't the language you describe include the string 000010, but the original language does not? To wit, I can take u = 0000 and v = 0, so it is in your language, but my only two possible choices for xyz are x = 00, y = 00, z = 10 and x = 000, y = $\epsilon$, z = 010, neither of which would be in the original language.

I realize that this an eight year old post so I'm unlikely to get a response, but I feel it should be said.

Comment: @DuncanRamage: You are entirely correct, and I can only imagine that I misread the definition of $A$ when I answered this question, though I can’t imagine how. I don’t have time to think very hard about it right now, so for now I’ll just put a warning note in the answer and hope to get back to it. Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: @DuncanRamage: In case you’re still interested, I finally found time to add a correct answer to the first part of this question.